# What is the value inside pinctrl

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, device-tree, imx8

I am working on a board based on `iMX8MP` processor. I was looking at device tree source and there are a lot of pin muxing. For instance :

```
pinctrl_keys: keysgrp {
    fsl,pins = <
        MX8MP_IOMUXC_SAI1_TXD1__GPIO4_IO13         0x00000140
        MX8MP_IOMUXC_SPDIF_TX__GPIO5_IO03          0x00000140
        MX8MP_IOMUXC_SPDIF_RX__GPIO5_IO04          0x00000140
        MX8MP_IOMUXC_SAI5_RXD2__GPIO3_IO23         0x00000140
    >;
};
```

My question is: from where the value `0x00000140` came from ? What does it mean. I looked inside the iMX8MP reference manual but no information explain that value.

Comment: According to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/fsl%2Cimx8mp-pinctrl.yaml the last number is the "pad setting" value. It says "Please refer to i.MX8M Plus Reference Manual for detailed CONFIG settings". It seems that a login is required to access that manual and I couldn't be bothered creating an account just to download the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the imx8mp pinctrl device tree bindings is [Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/fsl,imx8mp-pinctrl.yaml](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/fsl%2Cimx8mp-pinctrl.yaml). Here it describes the `fsl,pins` property as:

```yaml
properties:
  fsl,pins:
    description:
      each entry consists of 6 integers and represents the mux and config
      setting for one pin. The first 5 integers <mux_reg conf_reg input_reg
      mux_val input_val> are specified using a PIN_FUNC_ID macro, which can
      be found in <arch/arm64/boot/dts/freescale/imx8mp-pinfunc.h>. The last
      integer CONFIG is the pad setting value like pull-up on this pin. Please
      refer to i.MX8M Plus Reference Manual for detailed CONFIG settings.
    $ref: /schemas/types.yaml#/definitions/uint32-matrix
    items:
      items:
        - description: |
            "mux_reg" indicates the offset of mux register.
        - description: |
            "conf_reg" indicates the offset of pad configuration register.
        - description: |
            "input_reg" indicates the offset of select input register.
        - description: |
            "mux_val" indicates the mux value to be applied.
        - description: |
            "input_val" indicates the select input value to be applied.
        - description: |
            "pad_setting" indicates the pad configuration value to be applied.
```

If we take your example, MX8MP_IOMUXC_SAI1_TXD1__GPIO4_IO13 is defined in [arch/arm64/boot/dts/freescale/imx8mp-pinfunc.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/arm64/boot/dts/freescale/imx8mp-pinfunc.h?h=v6.3.1#n499) as

```c
#define MX8MP_IOMUXC_SAI1_TXD1__GPIO4_IO13    0x17C 0x3DC 0x000 0x5 0x0
```

So the pad configuration register offset is 0x3DC. If we look at the i.MX8M Plus Applications Processor Reference Manual, the register at offset 0x3DC in the IOMUX Controller (IOMUXC) is SW_PAD_CTL_PAD_SAI1_TXD1 SW PAD Control Register (IOMUXC_SW_PAD_CTL_PAD_SAI1_TXD1):

| Field | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 8 PE | Pull Select Field Select one out of next values for pad: SAI1_TXD1 0 PE_0_PULL_DISABLE — Pull Disable **1 PE_1_PULL_ENABLE — Pull Enable** |
| 7 HYS | Input Select Field Select one out of next values for pad: SAI1_TXD1 **0 HYS_0_CMOS — CMOS** 1 HYS_1_SCHMITT — Schmitt |
| 6 PUE | Pull Up / Down Config. Field Select one out of next values for pad: SAI1_TXD1 0 PUE_0_WEAK_PULL_DOWN — Weak pull down **1 PUE_1_WEAK_PULL_UP — Weak pull up** |
| 5 ODE | Open Drain Field Select one out of next values for pad: SAI1_TXD1 **0 ODE_0_OPEN_DRAIN_DISABLE — Open Drain Disable** 1 ODE_1_OPEN_DRAIN_ENABLE — Open Drain Enable |
| 4 FSEL | Slew Rate Field Select one out of next values for pad: SAI1_TXD1 **0 FSEL_0_SLOW_SLEW_RATE — Slow Slew Rate (SR=1)** 1 FSEL_1_FAST_SLEW_RATE — Fast Slew Rate (SR=0) |
| 3 - | This field is reserved. Reserved |
| 2–1 DSE | Drive Strength Field Select one out of next values for pad: SAI1_TXD1 **00 DSE_X1 — X1** 10 DSE_X2 — X2 01 DSE_X4 — X4 11 DSE_X6 — X6 |
| 0 - | This field is reserved. Reserved |

A pad configuration value of 0x140 is enabling the pull up, and disabling the Schmitt trigger. The other settings are irrelevant as this is an input pin.